# SSRS format issue when exporting to Excel

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with grouping, expression are basic Sum(Field!Sales).  I have then formatted as n2.   The format is fine when the report is viewed in SSRS but when exporting to Excel any 0 values are reported as 0.00000000000

Where there are values the number formats fine.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap the expression with the format function.

=Format(expression, #,##0.00) This fixed the Excel issue.